# Add a condition within the function with apply

Tags: r, function, dataframe, conditional-statements

I want to write a conditional function to apply to my dataframe.

The existing function is:

```
Proposed <- function(N_b,N_l,m,A,x.sqr,e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5,K_g,a,b,c,d) {
  e <- data.frame(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5,N_l)
  ee <- e[e != 0]
  CSi <- m * ((N_l/N_b) * ((a*K_g)^b) + 
            ((A * apply(ee,1,function(v) max(combn(v[1:ncol(ee)],v["N_l"],sum))))
              / x.sqr) * ((c*K_g)^d))
  return(CSi)
}
```

There are two folds to the conditions:

I want to add the condition that if `A > 0` then select `max(combn(v[1:5],v["N_l"],sum))`. But if `A < 0` select `min(combn(v[1:5],v["N_l"],sum))`

*Data*

A sample dataframe is provided (just a couple of rows)

```
dput(DATA)
structure(list(N_l = c(2, 4, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3), N_b = c(5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), m = c(1, 0.65, 1, 0.65, 1.2, 1, 1.2, 0.85), 
A = c(-12, -12, -15, -15, -9, -9, -9, -9), x.sqr = c(1440, 
1440, 2250, 2250, 810, 810, 810, 810), e_1 = c(21.8, 21.8, 
29, 29, 14.6, 14.6, 14.6, 14.6), e_2 = c(9.8, 9.8, 17, 17, 
2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6), e_3 = c(-2.2, -2.2, 5, 5, -9.4, -9.4, 
-9.4, -9.4), e_4 = c(-14.2, -14.2, -7, -7, 0, 0, 0, 0), e_5 = c(0, 
0, -19, -19, 0, 0, 0, 0), K_g = c(6340598.65753794, 6340598.65753794, 
6429472.98493414, 6429472.98493414, 6296482.86883766, 6296482.86883766, 
8140521.8248051, 8140521.8248051)), row.names = c(20L, 40L, 
60L, 80L, 100L, 120L, 140L, 160L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Why do you make a `data.frame`? If your values are all numeric, then a `matrix` is far faster, and your second line `e[e != 0]` creates a vector that is column-first unlisting of your frame. Because of this, `ee` has no dimensions, so `apply(ee, 1, ...)` is not meaningful (and should `Error`). You are likely going to need to provide sample data and expected output to be able to help with this.

Comment: This seems straightforward to me. Have you tried using an if statement? If so, why didn't it work?

Comment: @r2evans for some of the rows, some of the E_1, E_2, etc columns have zero terms. I do not want to include does in the consideration for the `combn` function. I only went to a data.frame cause that's examples that I have seen in examples for `combn` use.

Comment: @r2evans I have uploaded a sample dataframe

Comment: @LucasDeAbreuMaia I was getting an error which I think r2evans is referring to. The error from applying it with `nls` is Error in apply(ee, 1, function(v) min(combn(v[1:ncol(ee)], v["N_l"], sum))) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length

Comment: I'm still not certain what you mean by `e[e != 0]`, it makes no sense in this context. Do you mean that if *any* of the `e_*` variables in that new frame are zero, then discard the entire row? Or discard rows where *all* of the `e_*` variables are zero?

Answer (score 0):

`max(combn(v, n, sum))` is the same as `sum(tail(v,n))`, no `combn` necessary. For example,

```r
v <- 1:5
n <- 3
combn(v, n, sum)
#  [1]  6  7  8  8  9 10  9 10 11 12
sum(tail(sort(v), n))
# [1] 12
```

Similarly, `min(combn(...))` is just sum of the smallest two. With this, your `combn` calls can be simplified.

A simple function:

```r
func2 <- function(x) { # A=x[1], N_l=x[2], e_*=x[-(1:2)]
  decr <- (x[1] > 0)
  sum(head(sort(x[-(1:2)], decreasing = decr), x[2]))
}
```

For the sake of "interesting data", I'll negate `A` in every other row:

```r
dat$A
# [1] -12 -12 -15 -15  -9  -9  -9  -9
dat$A[c(2,4,6,8)] <- (-dat$A[c(2,4,6,8)])
dat$A
# [1] -12  12 -15  15  -9   9  -9   9
```

The use of it:

```r
apply(dat[,c("A", "N_l", grep("^e_", colnames(dat), value = TRUE))],
      1, func2)
#    20    40    60    80   100   120   140   160 
# -16.4  29.4 -26.0  44.0  -9.4  17.2  -9.4  17.2
```

(Assign this to a new variable in your frame if you'd like.)

**Decomposition:** let's debug it and run through the first row:

```r
debug(func2)
# debugging in: FUN(newX[, i], ...)
# debug at #1: {
#     decr <- (x[1] > 0)
#     sum(head(sort(x[-(1:2)], decreasing = decr), x[2]))
# }
# Browse[2]> 
x
#     A   N_l   e_1   e_2   e_3   e_4   e_5 
# -12.0   2.0  21.8   9.8  -2.2 -14.2   0.0
```

Our `x` variable has *everything*, so we'll need to reference them individually. We could use `x["A"]` instead of `x[1]`, which would be clearer to read. Over to you.

```r
# Browse[2]> 
decr <- (x[1] > 0)
# Browse[2]> 
decr
#     A 
# FALSE 
# Browse[2]> 
sort(x[-(1:2)], decreasing = decr)
#   e_4   e_3   e_5   e_2   e_1 
# -14.2  -2.2   0.0   9.8  21.8
```

Okay, so in this row, `A` is less than 0, so we want the `N_l` (2) *lowest* values, so when we sort them, the lowest are first.

```r
# Browse[2]> 
head(sort(x[-(1:2)], decreasing = decr), x[2])
#   e_4   e_3 
# -14.2  -2.2 
# Browse[2]> 
sum(head(sort(x[-(1:2)], decreasing = decr), x[2]))
# [1] -16.4
```

We'll repeat for the second row, where I changed `A` to be positive (and now `N_l` is 4):

```r
# debugging in: FUN(newX[, i], ...)
# debug at #1: {
#     decr <- (x[1] > 0)
#     sum(head(sort(x[-(1:2)], decreasing = decr), x[2]))
# }
x
#     A   N_l   e_1   e_2   e_3   e_4   e_5 
#  12.0   4.0  21.8   9.8  -2.2 -14.2   0.0 
decr <- (x[1] > 0)
decr
#    A 
# TRUE 
sort(x[-(1:2)], decreasing = decr)
#   e_1   e_2   e_5   e_3   e_4 
#  21.8   9.8   0.0  -2.2 -14.2 
head(sort(x[-(1:2)], decreasing = decr), x[2])
#  e_1  e_2  e_5  e_3 
# 21.8  9.8  0.0 -2.2 
sum(head(sort(x[-(1:2)], decreasing = decr), x[2]))
# [1] 29.4
```

Repeating through them all. (If you're doing this on the console, either reload/redefine the function, or call `undebug(func2)`.